# Get the folder name of the current page ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a navigation bar that I have inside a bulletedList.  My intention in doing that is to be able to change the classes based on where the current page sits on the site.  I have code that can find the current filename, but **I want to be able to retrieve the name of the folder that the current file is located**.  How do I do this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] file = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Split('/'); 
    string fileName = file[file.Length-1];

    if (fileName == "Dashboard.aspx")
    {
        MainNavList.Items.FindByText("Dashboard").Attributes.Add("class", "active");
    }
}
```

Comment: string fileName = file[file.Length - 2]; would give you the folder before the filename? Not sure what will happen if you do this for a page in the root. Might want to test if file.Length > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Yeronimo! All I did was change -1 to -2 and put in the name of my folder called "Dashboard".  This is what worked for me:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] file = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Split('/'); 
    string fileName = file[file.Length-2];

    if (fileName == "Dashboard")
    {
        MainNavList.Items.FindByText("Dashboard").Attributes.Add("class", "active");
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

With `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` you can get the current URL path.

As example if the page I was visiting was:

`http://www.website.com/Directory1/Directory2/Page.aspx`

Then it would output the string which you could use `split()`:

`/Directory1/Directory2/Page.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Request.MapPath` or `Request.PhysicalPath` to get location of ASPX file on disk.